# ¿Cómo se extrae un texto de un carrusel, desplazándose a través de él?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

Quiero obtener el texto de [esta página web](http://www.leparisien.fr/elections/municipales/municipales-a-paris-notre-simulateur-pour-savoir-quel-candidat-vous-correspond-le-mieux-05-03-2020-8273238.php) y los siguientes textos al hacer clic en el botón "Oui" o "No", que estará en el mismo lugar, y almacenarlos como un archivo json :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Intento con Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Programs\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://google.com/')
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Programs\chromedriver")

questions=[] #List to store questions the survey
driver.get("http://www.leparisien.fr/elections/municipales/municipales-a-paris-notre-simulateur-pour-savoir-quel-candidat-vous-correspond-le-mieux-05-03-2020-8273238.php")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="lxml")
for a in soup.findAll('div',href=True, attrs={'id':'root'}):
    question = a.find('div', attrs={'style': 'text-align: left; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; height: 50px; position: relative; margin-left: 18px; font-size: 20px;'})
    print(question.text)
    questions.append(question.text)
    print("question: ",question)
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>python3 text_scraper.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63980/devtools/browser/106c67f8-af8a-4230-8ec9-d7eb13fb8110
[30396:6884:0520/120628.687:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
```

## Intento con javascript

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('http://www.leparisien.fr/elections/municipales/municipales-a-paris-notre-simulateur-pour-savoir-quel-candidat-vous-correspond-le-mieux-05-03-2020-8273238.php');

    const pollFrame = page.frames().find(
      frame => frame.url() === 'https://livemixr-assets.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/quel-candidat/index.html'
    );

    // getting first question
    const data = await pollFrame.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector('html > body > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > h4').innerText
    );

    console.log(data);

    // clicking on an answer
    await page.$x('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/label[1]')
    const elements = await page.$x('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/label[1]')
    await elements[0].click()

    // getting second question
    const data2 = await pollFrame.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector('html > body > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > h4').innerText
    );

    console.log(data2);


    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Pero solo me devuelve el primero:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping>node scraper.js
Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation du métro ?
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at main (C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\scraper.js:24:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
```

Entonces, ¿cómo extraer texto desde un carousel?

Comment: Navegando por la pagina veo que esa pregunta está dentro de un iframe diferente al principal. Y no veo en tu codigo un cambio de frame. Tendrias que cambiar a ese frame responder la pregunta tomar el texto que necesites y volver al frame principal.

Comment: @j.barrio Gracias para tu comentario. Sí, pero ¿cómo se responde a la pregunta y itera para tomar el texto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes conseguirlo todo con Selenium emulando la interacción de un usuario real y capturando el texto.

No tengo muy claro la salida en forma de JSON que esperas, pero puedes obtener un json con la siguiente estructura:

```
{"Transports": {
    "Pregunta 1": [
         "Respuesta A",
         "Respuesta B"], 
     "Pregunta 2": [
     ...]
  ...}
}
```

Los pasos serían:

- Aceptar el popup de cokiees si aparece, en cumpliminento de [GDPR, and the ePrivacy Directive](https://gdpr.eu/cookies/).
- Localizar el iframe con el carrusel y movernos a él.
- Iterar hasta la última pregunta.
- En cada iteracición obtner el txto del ámbito de la pregunta, la pregunta. Localizamos todos los radiobuttons con las respuestas e iteramos sobre ellos para obtener el texto de cada uno.

---

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
location = "http://www.leparisien.fr/elections/municipales/municipales-a-paris-notre-simulateur-pour-savoir-quel-candidat-vous-correspond-le-mieux-05-03-2020-8273238.php"
driver.get(location)

# Aceptar popup de cookies si aparece
try:
    eu_cookies_acept = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.ID,
              "didomi-notice-agree-button")
            )
        ).click()
except:
    pass

iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".element > iframe:nth-child(1)")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", iframe)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)


datos = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

ultima_pregunta = None
while True:
    ambito = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "div.ant-row:nth-child(4) > h4:nth-child(1)"
        ).text
    pregunta = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "div.ant-row:nth-child(5) > h4:nth-child(1)"
        ).text
    opciones = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
        "ant-radio-button-wrapper"
        )
    if ultima_pregunta == pregunta:
        break
    ultima_pregunta = pregunta
    for opcion in opciones:
        datos[ambito][pregunta].append(opcion.text)
    opcion.click()
driver.quit()

json_data = json.dumps(datos, insent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Salida:

> ```
> >>> print(json_data)
> {
>     "Transports": {
>         "Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation du métro ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il faire payer le stationnement des deux-roues ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il interdire les bus de tourisme dans la capitale ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il piétonniser les quatre arrondissements centraux de la capitale ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il réduire le nombre de places de stationnement en surface ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il rendre le Vélib' gratuit ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il renforcer la vidéoverbalisation ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il rouvrir à la circulation les voies sur berges ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il interdire les trottinettes électriques ? (free floating)": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Le périphérique doit-il...": [
>             "... être supprimé",
>             "... comprendre une voie pour bus et covoiturage",
>             "... être préservé"
>         ],
>         "Les transports doivent-ils être rendus gratuits...": [
>             "... uniquement pour les seniors",
>             "... pour les mineurs et les seniors",
>             "... pour tout le monde",
>             "Non, ils doivent rester payants"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Sports et Loisirs": {
>         "Faut-il demander l'annulation des Jeux olympiques ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il mettre fin à la pratique du tirage au sort pour le conservatoire ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Sécurité": {
>         "Faut-il augmenter le nombre de caméras de vidéo-surveillance dans la rue ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il créér une police municipale ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Le future police municipale doit-elle être armée ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Propreté": {
>         "Faut-il augmenter le montant des amendes (jets de mégots, urine, dépôt d'ordures...) ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il privatiser le ramassage des déchets ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Logement": {
>         "À Paris, la société Airbnb doit-elle être ...": [
>             "... plus règlementée",
>             "... plus contrôlée",
>             "... interdite"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il baisser le nombre de nuitées autorisées à la location sur Airbnb (120 jours actuellement) ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il maintenir l'encadrement des loyers?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "En priorité, l'accès au logement social doit-il être attribué ...": [
>             "... aux classes moyennes",
>             "... aux travailleurs sociaux",
>             "... aux travailleurs pauvres"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il accroître le nombre de logements sociaux ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Finances": {
>         "En matière de finances, faut-il ...": [
>             "... réduire la dette de la ville",
>             "... continuer à recourir à l'emprunt",
>             "... augmenter les impôts locaux (pour tous ou pour les plus riches seulement)"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Environnement": {
>         "Faut-il interdire les animaux sauvages dans les cirques ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il proposer une alternative végétarienne tous les jours dans les cantines ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il piétonniser les abords des écoles ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Quelle est la priorité pour améliorer l'environnement ?": [
>             "Planter des milliers d'arbres",
>             "Filtrer les particules dans l'air des écoles",
>             "Interdire l'accès au Crit'air 3 et plus"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Education": {
>         "En cas de grèves, faut-il un service minimum pour les crèches et les écoles ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Faut-il revenir à la semaine de 4 jours dans les écoles ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ],
>         "Les tarifs des cantines scolaires doivent-ils ... ?": [
>             "... être baissés",
>             "... être rendus gratuits",
>             "... être maintenus"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Commerce": {
>         "Faut-il étendre le travail du dimanche ?": [
>             "Oui",
>             "Non"
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```

En mi caso uso Firefox (GeckoDriver), el error que tienes en tu caso con ChromeDriver parece ser un bug del propio driver de Chrome:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/61321143/7131499